# Mac suddenly shuts down and doesn't respond

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch Early 2013) has been crashing abruptly. This is especially happening when I keep my machine in sleep mode.
Scenario:

When my machine goes to sleep, it won't respond to any of the key strokes or the trackpad to wake up. It goes blank and when I try to force restart using the long press on the power button, it doesn't boot up. I just leave my laptop alone for 10 minutes and then try force booting it up using the power button. Then, it shows a screen with english and some other foreign language text saying "Your Mac is going to be restarted because of some problem" and then the Apple logo and boot up screen appears. Once its restarted, the following error dialog appears.

[image]

> The following is the log message: Anonymous UUID:
>   ACB21B63-00B8-7766-08C5-38AE2D320F9C
>
> Fri Apr 14 08:12:44 2017
>
> *** Panic Report *** panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff7f8a5bebd5): "GPU Panic: [] 2 0 a0 99 0 8 5 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error
>   0x00137310: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x103e00000
>   0xffffff9201060000 0x0e7150a2, D3,
>   P0/4\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.12.9/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
>   Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff81f30c3340 :
>   0xffffff80076d7b92  0xffffff81f30c33c0 : 0xffffff7f8a5bebd5 
>   0xffffff81f30c34a0 : 0xffffff7f8840534c  0xffffff81f30c3560 :
>   0xffffff7f884d3060  0xffffff81f30c35a0 : 0xffffff7f886672d7 
>   0xffffff81f30c35d0 : 0xffffff7f88439fb1  0xffffff81f30c3780 :
>   0xffffff7f886e49ce  0xffffff81f30c3800 : 0xffffff7f886e47da 
>   0xffffff81f30c3820 : 0xffffff7f88406485  0xffffff81f30c38b0 :
>   0xffffff7f88409aff  0xffffff81f30c3ab0 : 0xffffff7f8840b3bf 
>   0xffffff81f30c3b90 : 0xffffff7f885ae7d8  0xffffff81f30c3c40 :
>   0xffffff7f883b5b85  0xffffff81f30c3cc0 : 0xffffff7f8839ef58 
>   0xffffff81f30c3d40 : 0xffffff7f883a1c51  0xffffff81f30c3db0 :
>   0xffffff7f883a1946  0xffffff81f30c3e20 : 0xffffff7f8803f3ad 
>   0xffffff81f30c3e60 : 0xffffff7f8803e566  0xffffff81f30c3e90 :
>   0xffffff7f8803a569  0xffffff81f30c3ef0 : 0xffffff8007cb2176 
>   0xffffff81f30c3f40 : 0xffffff8007caffe1  0xffffff81f30c3f80 :
>   0xffffff8007cb00d6  0xffffff81f30c3fb0 : 0xffffff80077c6537 
>         Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
>            com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f8802f000->0xffffff7f88069fff
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1A48C605-D609-381F-90AB-C2547D2D0D12]@0xffffff7f87f54000
>            com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[4EB2843C-C821-3AD0-B333-575FD6ED6FB1]@0xffffff7f8839d000->0xffffff7f883acfff
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f8802f000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1A48C605-D609-381F-90AB-C2547D2D0D12]@0xffffff7f87f54000
>            com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.12.9)[154B0440-E3AE-3639-AB05-C7C4D03384C2]@0xffffff7f8a5b0000->0xffffff7f8a5c3fff
>               dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.12.9)[9E403CC1-B0BD-320E-B2BA-812490DF1671]@0xffffff7f8a5a8000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7f88b43000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1A48C605-D609-381F-90AB-C2547D2D0D12]@0xffffff7f87f54000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f8802f000
>               dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[C49819CE-729A-36B2-9AC1-744A43DC236F]@0xffffff7f8a5ab000
>            com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1)[7C8DF8B7-32F9-3EFF-9B5A-E8EAD8EB3A42]@0xffffff7f883b4000->0xffffff7f8862cfff
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1A48C605-D609-381F-90AB-C2547D2D0D12]@0xffffff7f87f54000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[4EB2843C-C821-3AD0-B333-575FD6ED6FB1]@0xffffff7f8839d000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7f8802f000
>               dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.12.9)[C5A263AD-4212-31A1-9DE2-A73A25F2ADC0]@0xffffff7f883ad000
>            com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.1)[EB8A5980-AB59-368A-8244-60A00C7A933C]@0xffffff7f88638000->0xffffff7f887e6fff
>               dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1.0)[7C8DF8B7-32F9-3EFF-9B5A-E8EAD8EB3A42]@0xffffff7f883b4000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1A48C605-D609-381F-90AB-C2547D2D0D12]@0xffffff7f87f54000
>
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
>
> Mac OS version: 15G1421
>
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Fri Feb 17 10:21:18 PST
>   2017; root:xnu-3248.60.11.4.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
>   9B4679AF-7EE6-3BCE-9DD7-C30975A80BB3 Kernel slide:
>   0x0000000007400000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007600000
>   __HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007500000 System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)
>
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 30857863075419 last loaded kext at
>   2525708770607: com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice    1.0.1 (addr
>   0xffffff7f8a6ca000, size 40960) last unloaded kext at 2718569826675:
>   com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8a6c3000, size 28672)
>   loaded kexts: com.sophos.kext.oas 9.6.52 com.sophos.nke.swi   9.5.50
>   com.carbonblack.CbOsxSensorNetmon 1701.03.52fc5
>   com.displaylink.driver.DisplayLinkDriver  2.6.0 (75598)
>   com.carbonblack.CbOsxSensorProcmon    1701.03.52fc5
>   com.bit9.cbsystemproxy    1701.03.52fc5 com.sophos.driver.devctrl 9.5.50
>   com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.70 com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0
>   com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.22.0
>   com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.6.0d0
>   com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim  1.0.0
>   com.apple.filesystems.autofs  3.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver  124
>   com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 274.12
>   com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry  1 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient  3.6.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 274.12
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  4.4.6f1
>   com.apple.GeForce 10.1.0 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics 10.1.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl  3.12.9 com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1
>   com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 3.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU  208
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri   10.1.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP   3.0.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.13
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    245.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard   245.4
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib   1.0.0
>   com.apple.BootCache   38 com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC   1.7.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.8.5
>   com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 1040.1.1a6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    3.1.8
>   com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI  1.0.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC  4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient   218.0.0
>   com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 163 com.apple.security.quarantine   3
>   com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 218.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice   1.0.1
>   com.apple.kext.triggers   1.0 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
>   com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib  525 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
>   com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal  10.1.0
>   com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman    10.1.0
>   com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder 1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 108.2.3
>   com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.12.9
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.4.6f1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController   274.12
>   com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily   274.12 com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily    204.4
>   com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.14d1
>   com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   6.0.0d7
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2  205.11
>   com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl  3.12.9
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily  1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.14d1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily  2.4.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.7.7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch   250.5
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    900.4.1
>   com.apple.driver.usb.networking   5.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  1.0.1
>   com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub  1.0.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter  4.1.3
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily  4.1.3
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter   2.0.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  4.0.4
>   com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily   6.0.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 1110.26
>   com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b8
>   com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.2
>   com.apple.driver.corecapture  1.0.4 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  2.8.1
>   com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI 1.0.1
>   com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI  1.0.1
>   com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI 1.0.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   900.4.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily   1.0.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties  1.0.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime  2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1 com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
>   com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager   1.0
>   com.apple.driver.DiskImages   417.4 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily    31
>   com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
>   com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   2.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    4.0 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
>   com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily  1.4 com.apple.kec.Libm  1
>   com.apple.kec.pthread 1 com.apple.kec.corecrypto  1.0 Model:
>   MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B0B, 4 processors, Intel Core i7,
>   2.8 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA
>   GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB,
>   DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020 Memory
>   Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD,
>   0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020 AirPort:
>   spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom
>   BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6) Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3
>   services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: Wi-Fi,
>   AirPort, en0 Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB USB
>   Device: USB 2.0 Bus USB Device: Hub USB Device: Hub USB Device: Apple
>   Internal Keyboard / Trackpad USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub USB Device:
>   Bluetooth USB Host Controller USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus USB Device: Hub
>   USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
>   Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4

Could anyone please help.

This is my information about my mac:
[image]

Comment: I assume you are on El Capitan? This looks like an issue with your driver.

Comment: Seems to be a GPU issue according to the panic, but it's not for certain. Can you check the console app for the shutdown cause? Run Apple Diagnostics/a GPU stress test like Unigine Heaven? Confirm that the other panics have similar logs?

Comment: Do you have a dedicated GPU? If so, what's the model? If it's Nvidia, you can try downloading Nvidia's driver and using that instead of the built in MacOS drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance it appears to be a GPU issue, although that doesn't necessarily have to mean it's a hardware problem.

As a starting point you could boot into Safe Mode just to check if the issue is replicated. If so, then you'd want to run Apple Hardware Test.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Test the computer (i.e. use it, put it to sleep, try to replicate the crash)
6. To exit Safe Mode just restart your Mac as normal

If the problem persists in Safe Mode, then use Apple Hardware Test as follows.

**Run Apple Hardware Test**

Your model MBP uses Apple Hardware Test. To use this, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your MacBook Pro
2. Restart your MacBook Pro
3. Press and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key before the gray startup screen appears.
4. After a while, Apple Hardware Test (AHT) will start.
5. When prompted, select your language and click the right arrow.
6. When the AHT console appears, you can choose to run Basic tests by clicking the Test button. However, I suggest you select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox before you click the Test button.
7. Your test results will appear in the window in the bottom-right of the console.

**Note 1:** that the extended test will take some time. Take a note of the results and report back.

**Note 2:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Monomeeth It worked. But I returned my machine back to our service team and got a brand new one ;)